# good books on calculus with finite elements

Tags: calculus

In 2 next semesters, I teach calculus for top students of engineering. I would like teach based on a calculus's book containing good examples with nice applications, e.g. containing finite elements. In fact, I am searching for a good textbook on calculus with nice applications based on notions. Is it possible to help me?

Comment: T.M. Apostol's Calculus (vol 1 and 2) is a good one.